# C side effects in gcc (prefix/postfix operator and precedence)

Tags: c, gcc

i have small C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int  z[]= {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int i = 2, j;
    printf("i=%d  \n",i); 

    z[i] = i++;

    for (j=0;j < 6;j++ )
       printf ("%d ", z[j]);

    printf("\ni=%d \n",i); 
}
```

output:

```
i=2  
1 2 2 4 5 6 
i=3
```

The order of precedence to evaluate the expression is
  First, z[i] is evaluated. As i is 2 here, it becomes z[2].
  Next, i++ is evaluated i.e 2 is yielded and i becomes 3.
  Finally, = is executed, and 2 (i.e value yielded from i++) is put to z[2]

This explains the above output i.e 1 2 2 4 5 6

But if we change the above code from i++ to ++i    i.e

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int  z[]= {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int i = 2, j;
    printf("i=%d  \n",i); 

    z[i] = ++i;

    for (j=0;j < 6;j++ )
       printf ("%d ", z[j]);

    printf("\ni=%d \n",i); 
}
```

Then the Output is strangely different, which is:

```
i=2  
1 2 3 3 5 6 
i=3
```

if we go by the above precedence (what C spec says [index] are bound earlier than ++) then
the output should have been 1 2 3 4 5 6.

I just wish to know that why the above order of precedence does not explains this ?

my compiler is gcc 4.5.2 on ubuntu 11.04

Thanks and Regards,
Kapil

Comment: The `=` operator is **not** a sequence point. The assignment statement will invoke UB.

Comment: Good way to learn.. Keep it up..

Comment: @KingsIndian See, it's more frequent than weekly ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer Indeed ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`z[i] = ++i;` results in undefined behavior:

> **6.5 Expressions**
> ...
> 2 If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar
> object, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the
>  subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side
>   effect occurs in any of the orderings.<sup>84)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> 84) This paragraph renders undefined statement expressions such as
>
> ```
>     i = ++i + 1;
>     a[i++] = i;
> ```
>
> while allowing
>
> ```
>     i = i + 1;
>     a[i] = i;
> ```

Note that *precedence* only controls the grouping of operators and operands; it *does not* control the order of evaluation.

The side effect of the `++` operator in `++i` is *unsequenced* relative to the `[]` operator in `z[i]`; the compiler is not required to evaluate the two expressions in any particular order.  Also note that the *side effect* of `++i` need not be applied immediately after the expression is evaluated; it only needs to be applied before the next sequence point.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug, take a look at the [GCC non-bug section](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/#nonbugs_c). This kind of tests will cause *unpredictable results* and they know it.

> Modifying a value twice between two sequence points [...] leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: in this case, `i` is only modified once.

Comment: But it's also being used in a value computation that's *unsequenced* relative to the increment, which also results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
 z[i] = ++i;
```

is undefined behaviour

To quote from [C section of cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order)

> 1) If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to
>   another side effect on the same scalar object, the behavior is
>   undefined.
>
> i = ++i + i++; // undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

z[i] = ++i;

invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.faqs.org/faqs/C-faq/faq/ Questions 3.1 to 3.9. These are pretty much answers to all questions similar to your question.

But in short, order of evaluation between two sequence points (these are well-defined by C standard - C99 Annex C) is undefined behavior.

> Between two sequence points, an object is modified more than once, or is modified and the prior value is read other than to determine the value to be stored